# Best practise while using 'SQlDataAdapter'

Tags: sqldataadapter

There is common function I am using in my project for returning dataset. I am using a 'SQLDataAdapter' here. This works fine for 3 other projects. But in one of the projects, this function threw an error when run from one of the client machines. (Works fine on server machine).

Error:-
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Here is the source code of the function:-

```
Public Function Fn_Return_Dataset(ByVal sqlquerys As String) As DataSet
    ' This function is used to return a dataset for given query
    If mydb.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        mydb.Close()
    End If

    Dim dap As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquerys, mydb)
    mydataset = New DataSet()
    Try
        dap.Fill(mydataset)
    Catch Exdat As Exception
        writelog(Exdat.Message.ToString, "MYDATA", "FN_RETURN_DATASET")
        showmsg("Sorry.....Unable to return dataset")
    Finally
        If mydb.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            mydb.Open()
        End If
    End Try
    Return (mydataset)
End Function
```

Comment: What's your SQL engine (type/version). Do you use named instances?

Answer (score 0):

If your code works fine on server machine and not on client machine then you have communication problem. Check if your SQL engine has TCP enabled and if firewall is opened. You may have some DNS related/name resolution related problem - check server name in connection string - do simple ping with server name to check if client machine can resolve server name to IP.